# Gantt view in task list is empty

Tags: 2010, design, gantt-view

I created a gannt view to my task list. I set title, start date and due date. However when i open this view I can see that right panel is empty. How can I repair it?

[image: Gannt view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution for my case. I was using Internet Explorer 11 and it was an issue. When I opened my gantt view in Google Chrome finally I saw it working.

Comment: I can update based on a new computer running Windows 10: I get a blank screen in Edge, it works in IE11, It works in Chrome and Firefox when the groupings are uncollapsed by default, but not after collapsing groups.